# SSH remote server - display only "echo" on output in terminal

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, command, sh

I have bash script (for example):

```
ssh -t -t user@domain.com << EOF
    cd /home/admin
    mkdir test
    echo 'Some text'
    exit 
EOF
```

Can I display only "echo" command in terminal? It is possible?

Now all commands are displayed.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specifying the commands on standard input with `ssh -t` causes the commands to be echoed back, but you don't have to do that.

```
ssh -t user@domain.com "
    cd /home/admin
    mkdir test
    echo 'Some text'"
```

(The `exit` isn't really required or useful, so I left it out.)

Use single quotes if you want to prevent the local shell from interpolating variables etc in the string containing the commands.

To selectively display an individual command as well as its output, you can use something like

```
    sh -vc 'echo \"Some text\"'
```

although the nested quoting can start getting on your nerves pretty quickly.