# How to pass parameter to function in Jenkins pipeline and pass it to the ssh command

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, groovyshell

I have following script

```
    def Greet(name){
      echo "Hello ${name}" // printing output on console as Hello Amol
      sh 'ssh -i @hostId "echo Hello ${name}"' // not printing anything on console. print only echo  
}

node() {
       stage("Hello") {
             Greet('Amol')
       }
}
```

How to print the ${name} variable value with ssh command. Can someone please help

Comment: Where should ${name} be printed? In the target machine you are ssh-ing into? Or in the console output of jenkins?
Can you edit your question to maybe add an example output or what you expect the result to look like?

Comment: Expecting it should print on Jenkins console. I have certain commands which I want to execute on target machine for those I have to pass this ${name} as parameter to ssh

Answer (score 0):

In the `sh` command, I've replaced the single quotes `(')` with double quotes `(")` to allow variable interpolation. I've also escaped the `$` character before `name` using a backslash `(\)` to prevent Jenkins from trying to interpolate the `name` variable locally. For example like this

```
def Greet(name) {
  echo "Hello ${name}"
  sh "ssh -i @hostId 'echo Hello \${name}'" 
}

node {
  stage("Hello") {
    Greet('Amol')
  }
}
```

Comment: you're welcome, for alternative you can try 

***sh """
       ssh -i @hostId "echo 'Hello ${name}'"
      """***
[prefer on this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27040750/6173518)